# Conditional rendering if elements exist

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, reactjs, axios

I have React component which use axios to call data from MySQL and render that. Problem is, if I want to display message, if I don't have any data. My code look like this.

```
    render() {

    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.elements.length < 1 ? (
                <p>Elements doesn't exist</p>
            ) : (
                <ul>
                    { this.state.elements.map(element => <li key={element.id}>{element.name}</li>)}
                </ul>
            )}
        </div>

    );
}
```

This code works but it display error for half second befor rendering list. I know that problem is delay of request to MySL and call a data but how I can avoid that?

Comment: You can set flag for request i guess. Example, in initial state you have 'initialized' field as false. After the request you can setState and update it to true. In render method you also need to update the condition to show spinner or something while initialized is false so you cant see the 'element doesnt exist' message if request is not completed.

Answer (score 0):

Add setTimeout so by default it will wait for 1 min then render the data from DB

Answer (score 0):

Just change your condition like the following. Its working fine , even though your MySL request take more time to load data

```
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.elements && this.state.elements.length > 0 ? (
                 <ul>
                    { this.state.elements.map(element => <li key={element.id}>{element.name}</li>)}
                </ul>
            ) : (
                <p>Elements doesn't exist</p>
            )}
        </div>

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this situation, you need to show some kind of loading message until the API call is resolved.

```
axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d36cl')
        .then(function (response) {
        this.setState({loading: false})
      })


  }
```

Now in render function,

```
render() {
if(this.state.loading) return (<Loading/>)

    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.elements.length < 1 ? (
                <p>Elements doesn't exist</p>
            ) : (
                <ul>
                    { this.state.elements.map(element => <li key={element.id}>{element.name}</li>)}
                </ul>
            )}
        </div>

    );
}
```

Now the loading component will be shown until the you get response from API call.